# How to generate a user-defined class object dynamically inside a component function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular to design a page that has nested components. The parent component acts as the container and the child components are essentially mat-cards displaying user information (user name, id, address etc.). I want to generate the child components directly by clicking a button in the parent component (which calls a GenerateUser() function).

I have created a class (UserDetails) with the requisite fields (user name, id, address etc.). I generate the child components dynamically inside the parent component using an array of UserDetail objects (the html simply loops over the array to generate child components using @Input). Every click of the "Generate button" pushes a UserDetail object on to the UserDetail array. At the moment I have one UserDetail object created using "new" and push the same object to the array. It's not surprising that all child components get the same value.

For every new user I'd like to create an independent/new UserDetail object, initialise the id value and pass the object to the new child component being created. How can I dynamically generate UserDetails objects in the GenereteUser() function? The parent-component.ts is as follows:

```
import { UserDetail } from 'src/app/models/UserDetail';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-parent',
  templateUrl: './user-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-parent.component.scss']
})
export class UserParentComponent implements OnInit {

  addUsers: UserDetail [] = [];
  newUser: UserDetail = new UserDetail();

  private addTracker: number;   // no. of additions

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addTracker = 0;
    this.newUser.id = this.addTracker;
    this.addUsers.push(this.newUser);
  }

  GenerateUser(): void {
    this.addTracker += 1;
    this.newUser.id = this.addTracker;
    this.addUsers.push(this.newUser);
  }

}
```

As mentioned above, in the GenerateUser() function I'd like to generate a new UserDetail object, but Angular doesn't let me use "new UserDetail()" inside the GenerateUser() function.

Is there a way to dynamically generate a new object inside GenerateUser()?

I know that I can use

```
this.addUsers.push({name: xxx, id: this.addTracker, address: yyy});
```

but I don't want to go that way as the code becomes too verbose.

Comment: The `new UserDetail()` should work in the `GenerateUser()` method. What's the error?

Comment: @sr-js what error do you get?

Comment: @sr-js, use the spread operator https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest : `this.addUsers.push({...this.newUser})`, else all your users will be the same -a change in one change the "others"-

Comment: @Eliseo I think the spread operator should work, I'll go home and try. Thanks!!

Comment: @Eliseo, the spread operator works well. Thanks!!!